# Data is recognized but not rendered Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have an assignment that uses Vuetify and I want to render a table of "customer" data. My code worked fine with Vuetify 1.5, but now I am supposed to update to the newest version, which is 2.0.

The problem I'm running into is that my data is recognized by the program, but none of it actually shows up in the table. The exact number of rows are rendered to match my number of records, and Vue DevTools shows that my data is there, but The rendered html is just empty  elements. I attached screenshots below to illustrate my point a little better:

[image: Rendered webpage]
[image: Vue DevTools]
[image: Regular DevTools]

The project can be found at: https://github.com/apalmesano2/assign3_frontend.git

Here is a snippet of what my Vue template for the list of customers:

**CustomerList.vue**

```
<template>
  <main>
    <br />
    <v-container fluid grid-list-md>
      <v-layout column align-left>
        <blockquote>
          Welcome {{validUserName}}!
          <footer>
            <small>
              <em>&mdash;Eagle Financial Services, your Midwest Financial Services Partner.</em>
            </small>
          </footer>
        </blockquote>
      </v-layout>

      <v-layout column align-center>
        <v-flex xs6 sm8 md7>
          <v-alert
            v-if="showMsg === 'new'"
            dismissible
            :value="true"
            type="success"
          >New customer has been added.</v-alert>
          <v-alert
            v-if="showMsg === 'update'"
            dismissible
            :value="true"
            type="success"
          >Customer information has been updated.</v-alert>
          <v-alert
            v-if="showMsg === 'deleted'"
            dismissible
            :value="true"
            type="success"
          >Selected Customer has been deleted.</v-alert>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
      <br />
      <v-container fluid grid-list-md fill-height>
        <v-layout column>
          <v-flex md6>
            <v-data-table
              :headers="headers"
              :items="customers"
              hide-default-footer
              class="elevation-1"
              fixed
              style="max-height: 300px; overflow-y: auto"
            >
              <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
                <td>{{ props.item.pk }}</td>
                <td>{{ props.item.cust_number }}</td>
                <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
                <td nowrap="true">{{ props.item.address }}</td>
                <td nowrap="true">{{ props.item.city }}</td>
                <td nowrap="true">{{ props.item.state }}</td>
                <td nowrap="true">{{ props.item.zipcode }}</td>
                <td nowrap="true">{{ props.item.email }}</td>
                <td nowrap="true">{{ props.item.cell_phone }}</td>
                <td nowrap="true">
                  <v-icon @click="updateCustomer(props.item)">edit</v-icon>
                </td>
                <td nowrap="true">
                  <v-icon @click="deleteCustomer(props.item)">delete</v-icon>
                </td>
              </template>
            </v-data-table>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-container>

      <v-btn class="blue white--text" @click="addNewCustomer">Add Customer</v-btn>
    </v-container>
  </main>
</template>
```

And the script, although I don't think there is an issue here because the data is being fetched just fine according to the Vue DevTools:

```
<script>
import router from "../router";
import { APIService } from "../http/APIService";
const apiService = new APIService();

export default {
  name: "CustomerList",
  data: () => ({
    customers: [],
    validUserName: "Guest",
    customerSize: 0,
    showMsg: "",
    headers: [
      { text: "Record Number", sortable: false, align: "left" },
      { text: "Customer Number", align: "left", sortable: false },
      { text: "Name", sortable: false, align: "left" },
      { text: "Address", sortable: false, align: "left" },
      { text: "City", sortable: false, align: "left" },
      { text: "State", sortable: false, align: "left" },
      { text: "ZipCode", sortable: false, align: "left" },
      { text: "Email", sortable: false, align: "left" },
      { text: "Phone", sortable: false, align: "left" },
      { text: "Update", sortable: false, align: "left" },
      { text: "Delete", sortable: false, align: "left" }
    ]
  }),
  mounted() {
    this.getCustomers();
    this.showMessages();
  },
  methods: {
    showMessages() {
      console.log(this.$route.params.msg);
      if (this.$route.params.msg) {
        this.showMsg = this.$route.params.msg;
      }
    },
    getCustomers() {
      apiService
        .getCustomerList()
        .then(response => {
          this.customers = response.data.data;
          this.customerSize = this.customers.length;
          if (
            localStorage.getItem("isAuthenticates") &&
            JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("isAuthenticates")) === true
          ) {
            this.validUserName = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("log_user"));
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          if (error.response.status === 401) {
            localStorage.removeItem("isAuthenticates");
            localStorage.removeItem("log_user");
            localStorage.removeItem("token");
            router.push("/auth");
          }
        });
    },
    addNewCustomer() {
      if (
        localStorage.getItem("isAuthenticates") &&
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("isAuthenticates")) === true
      ) {
        router.push("/customer-create");
      } else {
        router.push("/auth");
      }
    },
    updateCustomer(customer) {
      router.push("/customer-create/" + customer.pk);
    },
    deleteCustomer(customer) {
      apiService
        .deleteCustomer(customer.pk)
        .then(response => {
          if (response.status === 204) {
            alert("Customer deleted");
            this.showMsg = "deleted";
            this.$router.go();
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          if (error.response.status === 401) {
            localStorage.removeItem("isAuthenticates");
            localStorage.removeItem("log_user");
            localStorage.removeItem("token");
            router.push("/auth");
          }
        });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I have a hunch I'm doing something wrong with my v-data-table and the template where I'm passing the props in but I can't figure out what's going wrong or how to fix it because even just hardcoded text in the  tags won't render in the table.

To access the page where the screenshots are after cloning the project, you would need to log in with the following credentials:

Username: instructor

Password: instructor1a

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the new syntax after moving to vuetify v2:

```
           <v-data-table
              :headers="headers"
              :items="stocks"
              hide-default-footer
              class="elevation-1"
              fixed
              style="max-height: 300px; overflow-y: auto"
            >
              <template v-slot:item="props">
                <tr>
                  <td>{{ props.item.customer }}</td>
                  <td nowrap="true">{{ props.item.symbol }}</td>
                  <td nowrap="true">{{ props.item.name }}</td>
                  <td nowrap="true">{{ props.item.shares }}</td>
                  <td nowrap="true">{{ props.item.purchase_price }}</td>
                  <td nowrap="true">{{ props.item.purchase_date }}</td>
                  <td nowrap="true">
                    <v-icon @click="updateStock(props.item)">edit</v-icon>
                  </td>
                  <td nowrap="true">
                    <v-icon @click="deleteStock(props.item)">delete</v-icon>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </template>
            </v-data-table>
```